# The number of legs of creatures/animals

Tags: scripture, animals, life

[Yayati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yayati) in his conversation with Ashtaka mentioned about two-legged, four-legged and six-legged animals.

> "Yayati answered, 'After falling from heaven, the being becometh a
> subtile substance living in water. This water becometh the semen
> whence is the seed of vitality. Thence entering the mother's womb in
> the womanly season, it developeth into the embryo and next into
> visible life like the fruit from the flower. Entering trees, plants,
> and other vegetable substances, water, air, earth, and space, that
> same watery seed of life assumeth the **quadrupedal or bipedal form**.
> This is the case with all creatures that you see.'
> ...............
>
> "Ashtaka asked, 'After death, the body is burnt, or otherwise
> destroyed. Reduced to nothing upon such dissolution, by what principle
> is one revived?' Yayati said, 'O lion among kings, the person that
> dies assumes a subtil form; and retaining consciousness of all his
> acts as in a dream, he enters some other form with a speed quicker
> than that of air itself. The virtuous attain to a superior, and the
> vicious to an inferior form of existence. The vicious become worms and
> insects. I have nothing more to say, O thou of great and pure soul! I
> have told thee how beings are born, after development of embryonic
> forms, as **four-footed, six-footed creatures and others with more feet**.
> What more wilt thou ask me?'
>
> [[SECTION XC, Sambhava Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01091.htm)

Although Yayati mentioned that there are beings with more than six foot. He did not tell explicitly any *number* more than six.

**Do scriptures of Hinduism mention any other numbers restricted to legs of creatures other than two, four and six**?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is mentioning of a creature called as [**"Sarabha"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharabha) ,  having eight legs , who dwells in snow mountains and is foe of elephants and lions etc.  i.e. he is a eight-legged beast.

This Sharabha creature is mentioned in [**Mahabharata**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a116.htm) -Shanti Parva- Rajadharmanushasana Parva- Chapter 117. This is a story of a dog transformed  into various animals like lion ,tiger ,elephant etc. by a  sage.

> **अष्टपादूर्ध्वनयन** : शरभो वनगोचर : |
>  तं सिहं हन्तुमागगच्छन्मुनेतस्य
>   निवेशनम् ||13 ||
>
> P 253 Some time after one day, a slayer of all animals, possessed of
>   great strength inspiring all creatures with fright, having eight legs
>   and eyes on the forehead, viz., a Sarabha, came to that spot. Indeed
>   he came to that very hermitage for the object of slaying the Rishi's
>   lion. Seeing this, the sage transformed his lion into a Sarabha of
>   great strength. The wild Sarabha, beholding the Rishi's Sarabha before
>   him to be fiercer and more powerful, quickly fled away, from that
>   forest.

---

This fabulous creature Sarabha is also mentioned in  [**Yoga-vasistha**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-sanskrit/d/doc272899.html) - Book VII - Nirvana prakarana part 2 -Chapter CXXXI - Bhasa's account of the worlds.

> पादाष्टकैरावलितात्मपृष्ठो मृतेऽम्भसः क्लेशकृतात्ममृत्युः ।
>  समाः
>   शतार्धं शरभोऽहमासं क्रौञ्चाचले काञ्चनकन्दरासु ॥ 36 ॥
>
> **pādāṣṭakairāvalitātmapṛṣṭho** mṛte'mbhasaḥ kleśakṛtātmamṛtyuḥ |
>   samāḥ śatārdhaṃ śarabho'hamāsaṃ krauñcācale kāñcanakandarāsu || 36
>   ||
>
> I lived for half a century as a Sarabha, a wild animal with eight
>   legs; I dwelt in the caves of Krancha mountain, and brought on my
>   death by falling down from a craig, in attempting to fight with the
>   raining clouds on high.

Thus in hinduism scriptures a eight legged creature is also mentioned.